# How to bind RadDataPager.PageSize to RadNumericUpDown.Value in code

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, telerik

I have a RadGridView, a RadDataPager and a RadNumericUpDown all defined in code.

Now i want to bind the RadDataPager.PageSize to the RadNumericUpDown.Value so the pagesize of the pager is changeable via the RadNumericUpDown control.

Thus i try:

```
RadDataPager dataPager = new ...;
RadNumericUpDown pageSizeSelector = new ...;

Binding b = new Binding();
b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
b.Source = pageSizeSelector.Value;

pageSizeSelector.SetBinding(dataPager.PageSize, b);
```

But this generates an error about the `dataPager.PageSize` not being a `DependencyProperty`. What i'm a missing?

**EDIT**
Thanks to Klinger i got it straight. `SetBinding` wants the Static Definition of the DP, not a reference to the instance.

```
Binding b = new Binding("PageSize");
b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
b.Source = dataPager;
pageSizeSelector.SetBinding(RadNumericUpDown.ValueProperty, b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only dependency properties know how to handle binding expressions.

Take a look on the control documentation to see if the PageSize property is a dependency property.

Comment: I know binding is possible. Telerik has a demo in which it is done in XAML.

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#DataPager/FirstLook and click on 'View Code'

Comment: @Dribbel: What they did is the other way around. The binding expression is set in the NumericUpDown, not in the DataPager. They are binding the NumericUpDown.Value to the DataPager.PageSize property, not the DataPager.PageSize to the NumericUpDown.Value . In their example the DataPager is the DataContext for the ConfigurationPanel and is set in code behind. If I am not mistaken, you could also get the same result using ElementName in the NumericUpDown binding expression.

Comment: The otherway around also doesn't work, pageSizeSelector.Value also isn't a dependencyProperty. I'm lost...

CODE:  
            Binding b = new Binding("PageSize");
            b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            b.Source = dataPager.PageSize;
            
            dataPager.SetBinding(pageSizeSelector.Value, b);

Comment: @Dribbel: Try: CODE: Binding b = new Binding("PageSize"); b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay; b.Source = dataPager; pageSizeSelector.SetBinding(RadNumericUpDown.Value, b);

Comment: Thanks, i got my understandings of bindings in code wrong. Now it works.